# Symfony 4 : You have requested a non-existent service

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection, symfony4

I updated my website from Symfony  3.4 to Symfony 4 and do a little change. But know I have this error :

**You have requested a non-existent service "D".**

Here my stack trace:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
You have requested a non-existent service "D".

  at vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Container.php:263
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('D')
     (vendor\symfony\routing\Loader\DependencyInjection\ServiceRouterLoader.php:38)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\DependencyInjection\ServiceRouterLoader->getServiceObject('D')
     (vendor\symfony\routing\Loader\ObjectRouteLoader.php:55)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\ObjectRouteLoader->load('D:\\IIS Websites\\Wizard\\src/config/routing.yml', 'service')
     (vendor\symfony\config\Loader\DelegatingLoader.php:40)
  at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader->load('D:\\IIS Websites\\Wizard\\src/config/routing.yml', 'service')
     (vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader.php:70)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader->load('D:\\IIS Websites\\Wizard\\src/config/routing.yml', 'service')
     (vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Routing\Router.php:56)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router->getRouteCollection()
     (vendor\symfony\routing\Router.php:367)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcherDumperInstance()
     (vendor\symfony\routing\Router.php:289)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure}(object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
  at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
     (vendor\symfony\config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php:43)
  at Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory->cache('D:\\IIS Websites\\Wizard\\var\\cache\\dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure))
     (vendor\symfony\routing\Router.php:302)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcher()
     (vendor\symfony\routing\Router.php:256)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:109)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))
     (vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:212)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(DebugHandlersListener), 'configure'), array(object(ValidateRequestListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(SessionListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(FragmentListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(ResolveControllerNameSubscriber), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(TranslatorListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(TraceableFirewallListener), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:44)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:125)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:190)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public\index.php:34)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Where is the code ? we're not magicians :-)

Comment: Can you show your code where is call this service?

Comment: I never call this service this the problem

Comment: `at Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory->cache('D:\\IIS Websites\\Wizard\\var\\cache\\dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure))` - that does not look good? Are you sure you properly configured paths for your cache?

Comment: Yes : `public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/cache/'.$this->environment;
    }`

Comment: Did you try remove your `cache`?

Comment: Yes a multiple time but I always get this error

Comment: clear the cache directory manually and try again, You don't have any service ?

Comment: I always clear the cache manually. I have some service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had the same problem when upgrading from Symfony 3.4 to 4.0. I am currently using annotations for routes, which was not the case when using Symfony 3.

It appeared that my framework.yaml router configuration (/config/packages/) was wrong.

`framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~`

It was in fact a copy/paste from old config.yml file. As I am using annotation for routes, removing the router key in framework configuration solved my issue. But you might also need to point to a specific routing configuration file under 'resource'.

You can use the following command to check if the specified resource path is correct :

`php bin/console debug:config framework`

Hope this will help !

Comment: Thanks for that, man this error message is terrible to debug

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance as I don't have an actual answer but this won't fit in a comment.

```
// From the stack trace
ObjectRouterLoader->load(D:\\blahblah) 

// ObjectRouterLoader::load()
public function load($resource, $type = null)
{
    $parts = explode(':', $resource);
    if (2 != count($parts)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid resource "%s" passed to the "service" route loader: use the format "service_name:methodName"', $resource));
    }

    $serviceString = $parts[0];
    $method = $parts[1];

    $loaderObject = $this->getServiceObject($serviceString);
```

The route object loader actually expects a string like service:method.  Your windows D drive path also has a colon so it passes the initial check but then wants to load a service called D.

So why is ObjectRouteLoader::load being called with an invalid argument?  That I cannot answer from the stack trace but I'm guessing that you have a problem in your app's Kernel::configureRoutes or maybe one of your routes.yaml files.

All I can suggest is that you try undoing whatever you might have done that is route related.  If that does not help then maybe start with a fresh S4 skeleton project and move your S3 app over a bit at a time.

Comment: I will restart with a fresh Symfony 4 skeleton project cause I don't found why he do this.